# Labview to make a program

Tags: controller, labview

I'm trying to control a vacuum gauge using an Agilent controller SGX-600 and so far i haven't found any kind of software for him.I've tried to make a program in labview using visa but a recevie the same error all over again "Error -1073807343 occured at Property Node (arg 1) in Visa Configure Port (Instr).vi->Advanced Serial Write and Read.vi.Can anyone help me.pls

Answer (score 1):

The explanation for that error code is `Insufficient location information or the device or resource is not present in the system.` This should be in the LabVIEW online help.

It sounds as if you are not wiring a valid port name or address into the serial write and read VI. Is the device connected to a serial COM port? Have you wired up a constant or control to the *VISA resource name* input and selected the correct port using the dropdown on this constant/control? Have you communicated successfully with the instrument using a terminal program? Have you communicated successfully with any other devices from LabVIEW on this PC?

To help any further than this, we are going to need to see your code. If you select your code on the block diagram and choose **Edit > Create VI Snippet from Selection** you can save a PNG file that you can attach here and actually has the LabVIEW code embedded in it; if your version of LabVIEW is too old to include this feature then just take a screen shot.

Also unless I'm mistaken the device you're talking about is an **XGS-600** and this model was originally made by Varian (which is why it doesn't sound like an Agilent model number). I couldn't find any reference to LabVIEW software for this instrument either, but you could certainly try asking on the NI forums in case anyone has since developed software for it that they would share.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here are a couple things to help us help you:

1. When posting questions please include the code you tried.
2. Please also include a link to the communication spec for your instrument.
3. If you get can error like Error -1073807343 please Google it first, tell us what type of error it is, and then clarify what part of it you don't understand.